# Select elements with values smaller than some number

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

With this line I can print out values that are bigger than 1999

```
 <xsl:for-each select="//ad[regyear >= 1999]" >
```

But I cant seem to find out how to print out values from 1998 and down.

Comment: I second @Anthony's question, adding, "When you tried that, what happened that was unexpected?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bigger or equals to `1999`:

```
//ad[regyear &gt;= 1999]
```

Smaller or equals to `1998`:

```
//ad[regyear &lt;= 1998]
```

Answer (score 2):

@Kirill gave the main answer, but in XSLT 2.0 you can also use `lt` or `le`:

```
//ad[regyear lt 1999]
```

which may be more readable. In some cases, existential comparison operators like `&lt;` can have unexpected hairy implications, and `lt` avoids those.

Answer (score 1):

**For readability I recommend *not* to use `&lt;`.**

**Instead of**:

```
//ad[regyear &lt;= 1998]
```

**I use**:

```
//ad[not(regyear > 1998)]
```

**Never escape the `>` char in an XPath expression** -- I am not aware of a case when this is necessary.

**Finally**, as Lars correctly mentions, in XPath 2.0 (XSLT 2.0) use the `lt`, `gt`, `le`, `ge` and `ne` value comparison operators and don't use the general comparison operators for comparisons between two values.

Comment: Of course, `regyear &lt;= 1998` is not always equivalent to `not(regyear > 1998)`... in particular, when the context node has no child element named regyear. This is one of those "hairy implications" of existential comparison operators. Instead, you could write `1998 >= regyear`, which would be equivalent to `regyear &lt;= 1998`.

Comment: Regarding "I am not aware of a case when this [escaping > in an XPath expression] is necessary" -- I agree. The spec says > "must, for compatibility, be escaped using either `&gt;` or a character reference when it appears in the string `]]>` in content, when that string is not marking the end of a CDATA section." While `]]>` could occur in an XPath expression, the escaping could be avoided by preceding the > with a space, which would usually be done anyway for readability.

Comment: @LarsH: Your first comment is very interesting and valuable -- we sometimes forget such "little details" :) Thank you.